# Can't authenticate users on Windows Server 2012 shares

Tags: authentication, samba, windows-server-2012, workgroup

I've been meddling for a while with a Windows Server 2012 Datacenter copy my university provided me with (via MSDN Academy Alliance) but I'm having an issue with setting up a share with NTFS permissions.

The situation:

- Windows Server 2012, fresh install
- Added file sharing role
- Set up a share with SMB Quick
- Added permission (share to everyone full control, NTFS to full control for admins, a group, and a user.
- Added a test user in the group.
- Checked if the port was open in the firewall (445 right?)

What happens:
When I try to access the share for another pc in the network, same workgroup, it asks me for login info, but no matter what I give him it returns "Access denied" or "\IP\share\ is not accessible. You might not have permission..blablabla"
Another share set up as full control to everyone in both NTFS and share permissions, works perfectly.

What could be the issue?

Additional info: Turning down encrypt data access seems to solve the issue, the PC I'm trying to connect from is a fully updated Win7 machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMB encryption is an SMB 3.0 feature.  You can find information on the supported SMB versions by platform here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/06/06/windows-server-2012-which-version-of-the-smb-protocol-smb-1-0-smb-2-0-smb-2-1-or-smb-3-0-you-are-using-on-your-file-server.aspx

Comment: then since the other PC has windows 7, it only has SMB 2.1 and doesn't work... that explains it! thanks mate.